# will string values defined in non static method get garbage collected with class object?

Tags: java, string, methods, garbage-collection, non-static

I have set of huge help texts which I want to hardcode in class. Lets say we have different enums for countries, I can create HelpTextInterface having method

```
public interface HelpTextInterface {
  public String getText(CountryEnum enum);
}
```

and subclasses HelpTextAsiaEnglish, HelpTextEuropeEnglish, HelpTextAfricaEnglish, HelpTextAsiaHindi  etc.

```
public class HelpTextAsiaEnglish implements HelpTextInterface {
  public String getText(CountryEnum country) {
    switch(country) {
      case CHINA:
        return "large text about china in english";
      case JAPAN:
        return "large string about japan in english";
      .....
      .....
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

I can call appropriate HelpText provider class according to country and locale. This way not all the text will be loaded in memory at once. Only the class which belongs to a particular country will get loaded. My question is that if I reassign a variable of type HelpTextInterface will the strings which are part of method also be garbage collected or removed from memory along with class object? For example

```
A. HelpTextInterface ht =  new HelpTextAsiaEnglish();
B. ht.getText(CountryEnum.INDIA);
.........
C. ht = new HelpTextAfricaHindi();
```

Query 1: when will the english strings belonging to all asian countries get loaded in memory, at step A or step B?

Query 2: will the english strings belonging to all asian countries get garbage collected after step C, as HelpTextAsiaEnglish() object is not referenced any more, the confusion is around classloader which I am not sure if it will unload class HelpTextAsiaEnglish after step C or not.

Query 3: My goal is to make sure that only one set of Strings are loaded in memory at a time, is there any better way to do this like making these strings member variables.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on implementation details, but the reference implementation HotSpot/OpenJDK will keep references to the `String` instances representing the literals, once they have been accessed by the code, at least as long as the code is reachable.

A class stays reachable as long as its `ClassLoader` is reachable and a `ClassLoader` stays reachable as long as at least one of its classes is reachable. So, since apparently, your `HelpTextInterface` implementations are located via the same class loader, they will all stay reachable once they have been loaded.

As it is implementation specific, it could be worse than that. A different JVM implementation could instantiate all strings of a class right after loading the class.

---

There’s not much sense in creating classes with the sole purpose of returning strings, especially, if you assume the need for reloading them. You should create files within your code base and read them via `getResource`, etc. These strings are not associated with code and can be garbage collected normally. Or use, e.g. [`PropertyResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) which already serves this purpose and provides a Java interface to textually defined resources.